# Exception in task not breaking immediately

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Some pseudo code to illustrate my problem:

```
public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
   try
   {
      var task1 = DoThisAsync(); // throws exception
      var task2 = DoThatAsync();

      await task1.Then(t => Handle(t));
      await task2.Then(t => Handle(t));
   }
   catch (AggregateException)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Whatnow?");
   }
}
```

And Then is defined as such:

```
// from https://gist.github.com/rizal-almashoor/2818038
public static Task Then(this Task task, Action<Task> next)
{ 
   var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<AsyncVoid>();

   task.ContinueWith(t=>
   {
      if (t.IsFaulted)
         tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception); // continuing task1 this line only gets hit
                                           // after DoThatAsync() is completed??
      else
      {
         try
         {
            next(t);
            tcs.TrySetResult(default(AsyncVoid));
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            tcs.TrySetException(ex);
         }
      }
   });

   return tcs.Task;
}
```

So my problem is that for some reason, even though DoThisAsync() throws an exception pretty early, I don't see "whatnow" until DoThatAsync() is finished.
This is not the exact code, I tried to simplify to not waste your time. If there's nothing here that explains this behavior let me know and I will add more detail.

**Edit**

For the purpose of this question we can imagine DoThisAsync() and DoThatAsync() are to asynchronouse methods that basically do the following:

```
DoThisAsync:
   Thread.Sleep(30000);    // wait a short perioud of time
   throw new Exception();  // and throw an exception

DoThatAsnyc:
   Thread.Sleep(240000);   // wait a long period of time
```

Comment: Can you add a complete example, because in a small example  that I made, this is not what happens and `DoThatAsync` is not called...

Comment: So I edited my question and now it looks more like the real code. Also, make sure DoThisAsync() is long enough (Sleep) before the exception happens, like one or two minutes, to give it time to start DoThatAsync()

Comment: This is still not a complete example. Please give an example of what you do in DoThis/ThatAsync()

Comment: Not sure what you mean, DoThisAsync() *does* throw an exception which I *do* catch, my only question is why do I not catch it before DoThatAsync() is finished?

Comment: I mean - post the code you use for DoThisAsync and DoThatAsync

Comment: I edited my question. I also added a comment in the Then definition that maybe explains the problem better

Comment: Your example `DoThatAsync` is fully synchronous. Is your actual code synchronous or asynchronous? (A fully synchronous method will run synchronously, even if it's marked as `async`).

Comment: @StephenCleary, it will run synchronously, but doesn't putting the async keyword on the method also cause all exceptions to be caught and stuffed into the returned task (rather than thrown synchronously)?

Comment: @MattSmith: Yes. He is seeing the exception as expected, but he's not seeing it *when* he expects it. The question is poorly presented, but I interpret it to mean that he does expect to see the exception at the `await task1` line but expects that `DoThatAsync` is not completed by that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your `DoThisAsync` starts a new task and the action of that task is what throws the exception--is that right?

In that case, the exception is stored within the Task.  The exception will not be rethrown unless you call a trigger method like .Wait, or .Result.  When you `await` the task returned from `Then`, it is causing that task's exception to be rethrown.

**Edit:**
Based on your edits showing the DoThisAsync:
When an `async` marked method that returns a Task causes an exception, that exception is stored in the Task (rather than allowing it to propagate).  If you were to remove the `async` keyword I would expect the exception to happen at the time DoThisAsync is called.

**Edit:**
From Stephen Toub's Async/Await FAQ: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx:

> What does the “async” keyword do when applied to a method?
>
> When you mark a method with the “async” keyword, you’re really telling the compiler two things:
>
> 1. You’re telling the compiler that you want to be able to use the “await” keyword inside the method (you can use the await keyword if and only if the method or lambda it’s in is marked as async). In doing so, you’re telling the compiler to compile the method using a state machine, such that the method will be able to suspend and then resume asynchronously at await points.
> 2. You’re telling the compiler to “lift” the result of the method or any exceptions that may occur into the return type. For a method that returns Task or Task, this means that any returned value or exception that goes unhandled within the method is stored into the result task. For a method that returns void, this means that any exceptions are propagated to the caller’s context via whatever “SynchronizationContext” was current at the time of the method’s initial invocation.

Comment: The Exception is both thrown and caught successfully, the problem is when. It only happens after DoThatAsync() completes. In other words, the line "if (t.IsFaulted) tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception);" in the *Then()* method only gets hit after DoThatAsnc() is completed. Should it get hit little after DoThisAsync() throws an exception?

Comment: No.  I would expect it to be thrown from the `await task1.Then ... ` line.

Comment: I see, let me ask this question differently, why does the line `await task1.Then...` only get hit after DoThatAsync() is complete? It's an asynchronous method the code should go straight to the next line shouldn't it?

Comment: First, as Stephen pointed out, DoThisAsync is not doing anything asynchronously.  The `await task1.Then ..` line is awaiting the completion of task1 before it runs (though in your case, task1 will always be complete at this point and thus the `await` here will also run synchronously).  However, your original question is more about exceptions and Tasks.

Comment: DoThatAsync() *is* asynchronous, I should have come up with an asynchronous example that does the same thing. However, your first comment to this answer pointed me to the problem. The problem in my pseudo code is that `await task2.Then ` will never get hit before task1 is complete, even though they have nothing to do with each other. I didn't understand this. It appears that as soon as there is one `await` keyword the method does not go further until that task is complete. I thought it did go further as long as we didn't use the result. Important thing is you pointed me in the right direction.